# shell script that displays a CPU utilization percentage on AIX servers

Tags: aix

I want to get the consolidated percentage like, at this moment when i execute a script it should display output like "`50% cpu utilization overall`" some thing like this.

Is there a way i can achieve this in AIX..!?

Answer (score 0):

```
CPU=`vmstat |tail -1 | awk '{print $14 + $15 }'`
echo "$CPU% cpu utilization overall"
```

This just adds the user and sys CPU usage from vmstat.